# Is ListTile mandatory when working with ListView?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

Is ListTile mandatory when working with ListView?

```
   ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${items[index]}'),
          );
// Is this mandatory to be ListTile 
// or can I just return 'any' widget (Container for example)? 
        },
      );
```

If it is not mandatory, then what are main the advantages/disadvantages to using one or the other?

[ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)
[ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html)
[ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ListTile is not necessary. ListTile is just widget with preset 'design' and props like title, leading, trailing. You can create your own widget and use it.